# sapply() returns list instead of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I have the following data frame -

```
   name amarks bmarks cmarks
1   A    25      30     40   
2   B    45      78     50 
3   C    75      72     29 
4   D    18      16     70  
.   .    .       .      .
```

Where name is the name of the person, amarks, bmarks and cmarks are the marks scored at different exams by the person. Now I am tasked to find out name's of the people who have scored max in amarks, bmarks and cmarks. Also I got to store it as a vector. I have solved it in the following way -

```
> max_name <- sapply(marks[,2:4], function(x) {subset(marks, x == max(x,
> na.rm = T), name)})
```

This gives me the correct answers but when I check the data type of max_name, I see that its a list when ideally I expected sapply to return vector.

Following are my observations -

```
class(max_name)

> list

typeof(max_name)

> list

is.vector(max_name)

> vector
```

Can somebody please explain what is happening over here. Am I missing something. Do I need to make any changes to my code so that it returns a vector?

Comment: First of all a `list` *is* a vector. Second of all, when you do something like `x == max`, you never know how many results you will get. It can be 1 or a 1 thousand. In R, only a list can store different size vectors in it, hence R returned a list. If you always want a single results per column, see `?which.max` instead. Also, what is your desired results? Wouldn't just `sapply(marks[,2:4], max,  na.rm = TRUE)` suffice?

Comment: Or maybe `marks$name[sapply(marks[,2:4], which.max)]`. Also, `subset` returns a dataframe. Theoretically, you could add `, drop = TRUE` at the end of your code and if there always a single `max` per column, you will get a character vector as a result.

Comment: Thanks David, that helped.

Comment: @DavidArenburg no reason to not put this into an answer.

Comment: Part of the motivation of the `map` functions in the `purrr` package was to avoid the mystery of the what the `apply` functions will return.

Comment: jtr13, well said. Vectorize() , which calls sapply() , returns a list too if the result is empty. I've just wasted two hours trying to work out why I was getting lists where I expected vectors. Bloody implementors. But I then decided to use purrr instead, and you've confirmed it.

Comment: And purrr::map_dbl() worked beautifully. Returns c() when the result is empty, just as consistency demands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems with your code:

1. `subset` method for dataframes has `, drop = FALSE` set as default which means that you will *always* will get a dataframe in return (unless you will explicitly specify `, drop = TRUE`). Hence, you will always get a `list` vector as a result because this is the only structure in R that can hold several dataframe together (also, please note the "Warning" section in the `?subset` docs regarding when and *if* you should use it).
2. `x == max(...` Can return unknown amount of rows because in each column there could be several values equal to the maximum value. Hence, most certainly you will get different length vectors as a result, and, well, only a `list` can hold different size vectors. If you only want a single result per column, you could use `which.max` for instance, which also automatically ignores `NA`s.
3. Finally, it is not very clear what did you actually expect in return rather a list? If there are more than one row in a column that equal the maximum, do you want both names? Or only the first? Either-way, below are few options

Let's add some `NA`s and some duplicate rows which equals to the columns maxs so we could see how results are differ

```
marks <- read.table(text = "name amarks bmarks cmarks
1   A    NA      30     40   
2   B    45      78     50 
3   C    75      NA     70 
4   D    75      16     70", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

marks 
#   name amarks bmarks cmarks
# 1    A     NA     30     40
# 2    B     45     78     50
# 3    C     75     NA     70
# 4    D     75     16     70
```

Basically, if you want *all* the `name`s we could just add `unlist` to your code

```
unlist(sapply(marks[, 2:4], function(x) {subset(marks, x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE), name)}))
# amarks.name1 amarks.name2  bmarks.name cmarks.name1 cmarks.name2 
#         "C"          "D"          "B"          "C"          "D"
```

Alternative way achieving the same without using `subset`

```
marks$name[unlist(sapply(marks[, 2:4], function(x) which(x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE))))]
## [1] "C" "D" "B" "C" "D"
```

Or even (a vectorization/over-complication trade-off)

```
marks$name[which(sapply(marks[, 2:4], 
                        function(x) x == max(x, na.rm = TRUE)), arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]
## [1] "C" "D" "B" "C" "D"
```

Or a fully vectorized solution (in exchange for using an external package, matrix conversion and generally ultra-over-complication)

```
marks$name[which(marks[, 2:4] == matrixStats::colMaxs(as.matrix(marks[, 2:4]), 
                                                      na.rm = TRUE)[col(marks[, 2:4])], 
                 arr.ind = TRUE)[, "row"]]

## [1] "C" "D" "B" "C" "D"
```

---

Though, If you just want the first maximum per column, we could simplify to just (which also handles `NA`s)

```
marks$name[sapply(marks[, 2:4], which.max)]
# [1] "C" "B" "C"
```